# How to print a JPanel into printer that has paintComponent override?

Tags: java

I created a graph in a JPanel with paintComponent function. Is there a way to print this graph?

When I try to call the JPanels paintAll from the print function its repeatedly calling the paintComponent. I want to physically print it, i.e., pass it to the printer job from my OS.

Here is the print:

```
public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex)
        throws PrinterException {
    double scaleX = pageFormat.getImageableWidth() / mainPanel.getWidth();
    double scaleY = pageFormat.getImageableHeight() / mainPanel.getHeight();
    double scale = Math.min(scaleX,  scaleY);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)graphics;
    AffineTransform Tx = g2d.getTransform();

    g2d.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableY());
    g2d.scale(scale, scale);
    System.out.println(scale + " Came inside");
    mainPanel.printAll(g2d);

    g2d.setTransform(Tx);
    return PAGE_EXISTS;
}

//mainPanel class has the method override as below

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! When asking questions, please make sure you explain your problem in as much detail as possible, and in this case desired outcome. If you put effort in helping people understand your problem, they will put more effort into helping you solve yours. I'm assuming here you are trying to find out how to visualise your graph? Or are you talking about physically printing your graphic using a "physical" printer?

Comment: “…the print function its repeatedly calling the paintComponent.” Yes, that is normal.  Often printing (and painting) is done one section at a time, with the Graphics object’s clip set appropriately before the paint methods are called.  Your paintComponent method should not be adversely affected by this.

Comment: I found the problem. I keep returning PAGE_EXITS from the print function without checking the pageIndex. In the begining of print, I check for pageIndex > 0 and return NO_SUCH_PAGE and it works perfectly now. Thanks for all the help. if(pageIndex>0) return NO_SUCH_PAGE;